# modal button events in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I make a modal must appear when I click delete button.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="confirm-modal-title">Confirmation Message</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <strong><p id="confirm-model-body"></p></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm-model-yes-button" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirm-model-no-button" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I make AJAX event only on yes modal button, when I click no modal button or `X` close nothing gets done but the second time when I click delete button of the same row and click yes the row will delete but also its get this message `alert(data.message)` why ? How can I prevent that without make event on no or `X` close?

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_librarian', function(){
    var librarianDataRow=$(this).closest('tr');
    var librarianId=parseInt(librarianDataRow.find('td:eq(0)').text());
    var librarianName=librarianDataRow.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    $('#confirm-model-body').text("Are you sure you want to delete "+librarianName+" data");
    $('#confirm-modal').modal({backdrop: 'static'});
    $('#confirm-model-yes-button').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/admin/librarian",
            type: "DELETE",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({id:librarianId}),
            success:function (data) {
                if(data.success == true)
                {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(data.message); //this message appear even when yes button after click no button or x close .
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: where is the element with class `delete_librarian`

Comment: it's a selector of the delete button that appear on each row in the librarian data table

Comment: While deleting , response yet success ,

Comment: yes but alert message shouldn't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you're saying but i think your problem should be resolved with replacing success statement in the ajax call :

```
    success:function (data,textStatus) {
        if(textStatus == 'success')
        {
            window.location.reload();
        }
        else
        {
            alert(data.message); //this message appear even when yes button after click no button or x close .
        }
```

or send success message in server like (in php):

```
$data['success'] = true;

echo json_encode($data);
```